# How to remove all elements for List<NameValuePair> Android

Tags: java, android

I want to remove all elements from the list. I've got this code:

```
private List<NameValuePair> httpQueryPairs; 
    httpQueryPairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    httpQueryPairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("A", foo));
    httpQueryPairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("B", bar));
    httpQueryPairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("C, "Help me i don't know how to delete all elements;)"));
    httpQueryPairs.removeAll(???);
```

Comment: are you looking for the `clear()` method? `httpQueryPairs.clear()`

Comment: please select that as an answer, there is no use to have that burried in comments /cc @Subler

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked docs for arraylist? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear()

use httpQueryPairs.clear()